# update node.js express api every minute by the current timestamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, express

I am trying to expose mySQL table as an api using node express. It works, the part that i can not get to work is filtering by a current timestamp and releasing that update every n minutes. I tried setInterval but the json that gets exposed is always the same and only has initial filtering and never updates for the next timestamp.
Here is what im doing:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const moment = require('moment');


const app = express();

var stamp = moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:00")

var update = function () {
    var stamp = moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:00")
};

setInterval(update, 

    10000);

var SELECT_ALL = 'SELECT sum(xxx as xxx, time, lat, lon FROM xxx where time = ' + '"'+stamp+'"' + ' group by time, lat, lon';


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "xxx",  
    user : "xxx",
    password : "xxx",
    database : "xxx",
    timezone: '+5:00'
});

connection.connect(err =>{
    if(err){
        return err;
    }
});



app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('hello from monitoring app')
});



var query = (q,a) =>{

    app.get(a, (req,res)=>{
        connection.query(q, (err,results)=>{
            if(err){
                return res.send(err)
            } else {
                return res.json({
                    data: results
                })
            }
        });

    });

};


query(SELECT_ALL,'/stats');


app.listen(4500,()=>{
    console.log(`products server is listening port 4500`)
});
```

This code exposes the query as api once, but does not update based on the new timestamp. I am not sure where i am messing up, but im expecting the setInterval to update the timestamp every n seconds, then timestamp (stamp) is fed to the select_all query, which should update the api.

Could you please tell me what i am doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are numerous conceptual and syntax issues with the code you have shown. If you can elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, I can offer some guidance.

Comment: i have a table in mysql database. is has the time column aggregated by minutes (2019/10/17 00:00:00, 2019/10/17 00:01:00....etc). I am trying to expose that table as an api . That works if i expose the whole table or if i just filter it for one timestamp like 2019/10/17 00:00:00. However, i am trying to filter by the current (live) timestamp every minute. So, here is what im doing in this code: generating a live timestamp every 10 seconds by doing setInterval and then pasting that timestamp as filter argument to the query.

Comment: I tried to wrap the whole thing in setInterval but it either led to the same outcome or just broke the code, based on the placement

Comment: So you want app API to set the update itself. When users hit the endpoint, they must only get the result of the query based on the update set by the API?

Comment: pretty much. i then access the api through ajax call in react and show the data filtered by this code. i tried doing it unfiltered but it is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with `mysql` so will assume your connection code and query works.

You need to update the module level `stamp` variable in your `setInterval` so the value is cached and set when users hit your `/stats` route. You were never updating the value previously.

```
function updateStamp() {
    stamp = moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:00");
}

updateStamp();

setInterval(() => {
    updateStamp();
}, 10000);
```

When a user then hits the route: `'/stats'` you will query the database using the stamp and return the `json` results.

See below for an example:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const moment = require('moment');

let stamp = null;

// db connection code
const config = {
    host: "xxx",
    user: "xxx",
    password: "xxx",
    database: "xxx",
    timezone: '+5:00'
};

let connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

function updateStamp() {
    stamp = moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:00");
}

updateStamp();

setInterval(() => {
    updateStamp();
}, 10000);

// express stuff
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello from monitoring app')
});

app.get('/stats', async (req, res) => {
    const SELECT_ALL = 'SELECT sum(xxx as xxx, time, lat, lon FROM xxx where time = ' + '"' + stamp + '"' + ' group by time, lat, lon';

    connection.query(SELECT_ALL, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);

            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            return res.json({
                data: results
            })
        }
    });
});

app.listen(4500, () => {
    console.log(`products server is listening port 4500`)
});
```

I highly suggest you add additional logging and breakpoints to help analyze the code.

Comment: I had a more detailed look at the demo code and there are so many issues that it will take a far more elaborate answer to update. But will try to tackle it now for you.

Comment: i just tested and i think it worked. thank you very much! I will study your code so i can understand where the issue was.

Comment: No prob, best of luck with the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `delay` in database level and maximize use of `mysql` `current_timestamp`

```
select sleep(60); 
select sum(xxx as xxx, time, lat, lon 
        from xxx where time = current_timestamp() group by time, lat, lon;
```

And also seems your `sql` script is broken on `sum()` function

```
var SELECT_ALL = 'SELECT sum(xxx) as xxx, time, lat, lon FROM xxx where time = ' + '"'+stamp+'"' + ' group by time, lat, lon';
```

Comment: i tried current_timestamp() and now() before - same result. It only releases the api once and doesnt update it the next minute. I think, the problem is somewhere lower in the code. But i am not confident really.

Comment: @NikitaVoevodin, how about using stored procedure to do this? so everything will be in backend process, since this is some sort of scheduled job?

Comment: like uploading to the database every n minutes an leaving this code be. i maybe will do that if i wont figure this out, but i would rather do it in this script if possible

Comment: sql query runs fine